# Adding new Item to CSLA EF4 pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, database, mvvm, entity-framework-4

I'm adding a new item to my CSLA BusinessList. But I can only add it with a 0 primary key because my items which I add is always null. And if I try: "Item temp= new item{...}" is this item not child of the list.
I'll post my Add function first and then some dataportals.

```
    public void ExecuteNew(object obj)
    {
        if (Model != null)
        {
            Temp = Model.AddNew();
            //Temp.FarbauswahlNr = 123;
            //Temp.Kurztext = this.Kurztext;
            //Temp.Ressource = this.Ressource;
            //Temp.Vari1 = this.Vari1;
           Model = Model.Save();
        }

    }
```

Now some DataPortals from my Business class and BusinessList class

```
    protected override void DataPortal_Update()
    {
        using (var ctx = Csla.Data.ObjectContextManager<Datenbank.TestDBEntities>.GetManager(Business.EntitiesDatabase.Name))
        {
            Child_Update();
        }
    }

    protected override void Child_Create()
    {

        base.DataPortal_Create();

        BusinessRules.CheckRules();

    }



           private void Child_Insert()
    {
        using (var ctx = Csla.Data.ObjectContextManager<TestDBEntities>.GetManager(EntitiesDatabase.Name))
        {

            try
            {
                var data = new Datenbank.Farbe();
                data.Kurztext = ReadProperty<string>(KurztextProperty);
                data.Ressource = ReadProperty<string>(RessourceProperty);
                data.Var1 = ReadProperty<bool>(Vari1Property);
                data.Vari2 = ReadProperty<string>(Vari2Property);
                ctx.ObjectContext.Farben.AddObject(data);
                ctx.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }


        }
    }
```

Possible Errors : 
NullReferebceException was unhadeld ( because temp is always null )

Comment: Ok the Primary key isnt such a big Problem anymore. But my UI is freezing after Model.Save(); Anybody know why?

Comment: Frozen for few seconds or hanged? Let's attach debugger, pause the program to see the stack...

Comment: hanged. When calling Model.Save(); with my button.

Comment: Let's run inside debugger then pause execution, you'll explore the stack trace of the main UI thread to see WHERE it's hanged.

Comment: i did :D 

        public void ExecuteAktu(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                Model = Model.Save();
                // programm freeze
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

Comment: It can't be frozen inside a whole function but one single line! :) Isolate it. You may need to disable "Just my code" from options so you can see functions from other DLLs in your call stack.

Comment: Model.Save() is a given method from CSLA. i didnt it myself.

Comment: so how can i see "in" it?^^

Comment: Disable "Just my code" in debugger options, you'll see it's stack too (and with source files you'll see exactly where it hangs)

Comment: MusterConnectionDB.exe!MusterConnectionDB.App.Main() + 0x59 bytes

Comment: and the very last is : 
  mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes

Comment: got the Problem. CSLA 4.5 has got a bug wich makes u stick in the Save() method. Using CSLa 4.1 now. Thx at myself ;P

Comment: now im back to my old Problem. Temp is always null

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was: CSLA 4.5 has got a bug wich let your UI Freeze after the Save Command. Now im using CSLA 4.1 and it works just fine.